# puppet ignoring configuration

Tags: puppetmaster, debian-jessie

I've set up a puppet (3.7.2) master server on a Debian 8 Jessie box, but somehow the config directives I've written get ignored:

```
[14:24:43|root@puppetmaster:~] cat /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
[master]
server=puppetmaster
```

This is a very basic config, yet it fails to take into account my directive. If I start the master:

```
[14:33:54|root@puppetmaster:~] puppet master ; puppet config print |grep ^server
server = puppet
```

Same goes if I try to start it with arguments :

```
[14:35:29|root@puppetmaster:~] puppet master --server puppetmaster ; puppet config print |grep ^server
server = puppet
```

Same result if I try the above under the puppet user.

I just don't see what I might be missing.

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention : puppetmaster has no DNS entries, everything get resolved through host files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of issues with what you're trying to do.

1. the 'server' configuration item only makes sense in the 'agent'
   context; setting it under [master] has no useful effect
2. The documentation for "puppet config print" claims it works in 'agent'    mode, although I'm not 100% sure that's correct (it doesn't seem to actually work that way)

Interestingly, you can also use the "configprint" option, e.g.:
`sudo puppet agent --configprint server`
or
`sudo puppet master --configprint server`

and see what happens; for me it behaves the way I'd actually expect (returning the relevant value from [agent] and [master] respectively)

I would suggest "configprint" is doing what you need and you should use that instead of 'config print'

Comment: Also, the configprint and config print options are only looking at configuration files, not the parameters of the currently running processes

Comment: Looks like I might have missed the fact that the configuration was mainly used in the agent perspective.

And you got that right : puppet master --configprint server showed the correct value, which is "puppetmaster" .

This issue is thus closed.

Thanks !!!